# How to save and restore options for cmd.exe window?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, command-line, windows-registry

After installing Windows Vista when I run cmd.exe the font size is very small, not suitable size of console etc.... I need to configure it.

I suppose my configuration is stored in registy - I want to backup it and have ability to restore later, e.g. for windows reinstall or for new user. 
But I was not able to find it.

Where info about cmd.exe window is stored?
Thanks!

Comment: When I'm remembering correctly it is stored in the .lnk Simply create a link to cmd and configure it. rightclick the link then properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of the options are stored in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor` and the rest should be in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` and if you are looking for values to edit I would start with looking [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true). Once you get it the way you want you could easily extract it to a reg file or write it in a batch file.

Comment: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` seems to be a good place to configure font for all `cmd.exe`'s windows. I've used this procedure: Set the desired parameters in an instance of `cmd.exe` using GUI, then copy the settings to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` from its subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to find where it is stored in the registry, since it only takes a few seconds to configure it?

ie,

```
Run cmd.exe
Click on the icon at the top left of the window.
Click on Properties.
Click on Font.
Select your new font and size 
Press return (or click on OK)
```

The settings will be saved for next time.

It would probably be quicker doing it this way than editing the registry.

Comment: Do you think that I asked question just for fun? ;) I don't want to edit in registry, but only run reg-file in one click. Moreover there are software which run in old text mode and I expect they can be configured in the same way.

Comment: Try looking in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_system32_cmd.exe

Answer (score 0):

The solution of MaskedPlant worked for me. I exported the registry from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`. But in order to make your terminal look with the customizations applied in all its intances (even if you opened it via win+R < cmd or windows search for command prompt) you have to customize the cmd from both options at the moment you right clic on cmd, I mean from `Default` and also from `Properties` in order to get all the cmd instances changed when you execute the reg file, then you can export the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` and execute it in any win10 PC.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1127114)

Comment: I didn't require clarification from the asker in my answer.